# Unlock with lambda

Tags: concurrency, lambda, java-8

Is there anything problematic when unlocking a lock in a try-with-resource construct by generating a AutoClosable through a lambda expression?

```
lock.lock();
try (AutoCloseable auto = lock::unlock) {
    /*...*/
}
catch (Exception exp)  {
    /*...*/
}
```

I thought it might be slower or it might generate more garbage. But I couldn't really find any significant performance difference with (probably faulty) micro benchmarks.

Comment: It will generate more garbage.  Bound method refs involve an allocation.

Comment: @Brian Goetz: but the allocation can be optimized away if the code ever becomes performance relevant. This is likely what happened when this code was executed in a benchmark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend creating your own specialized interface to get rid of the declared `Exception`:

```
interface Cleanup extends AutoCloseable {
    public void close();
}
```

…

```
Lock lock=new ReentrantLock();
lock.lock();
try(Cleanup x=lock::unlock) {
    // action
}
```

It’s true that this might create a temporary object (the specification leaves this open to the implementation), but a single temporary object is no match for a modern JVM.

Note that this pattern can be applied to a lot of other use cases as well:

```
Runnable r1, r2;

try(Cleanup x=r2::run) { r1.run(); }
```

Here, both `Runnable`s are guaranteed to be executed. The advantage over `try {} finally {}` is that if both runnables throw an exception, these exception are chained using [`Throwable.addSuppressed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed-java.lang.Throwable-) while an exception thrown in `finally` hides an exception thrown in the `try` block completely.